# Stop Node.js upon GET (or POST) request to given URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, httpserver

I'm trying to write a simple Node.js http server which stops and exits its process when a given url is accessed: in this case, `/stop`. This is my program so far:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {

    response.end(function(){
        if (request.url === '/stop') server.close();
    });

});
server.listen(12345);
```

What I expect to happen is that the callback is called when the response finishes sending, and the server closes if the URL is `/stop`. However, all this ends up doing is it shows a blank page (which I expected) and does nothing else.

On the other hand, this program almost works if I omit `response.end()`:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {

    if (request.url === '/stop') server.close();

});
server.listen(12345);
```

It does manage to stop the server, but not until I terminate the GET request by closing the browser window.

How can I get the server to stop when I GET a certain URL without having to close the browser window? (It would be nice if I could send a "Server stopped" message to the browser, too.)

NOTE: I know that I don't actually have the code to differentiate between GET and POST requests, but I would like to be able to handle both, and I'm assuming the answer isn't different depending upon the type of request.

Comment: Have you tried `process.exit()`?

Comment: @RyanGill No! Just judging from the name of the method, it sounds like it might work. Is it something I need to `require`?

Comment: @RyanGill that works, thanks.